# How do i get an aggregate percentage on two concatenated codes denoted by a value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, algorithm, percentage

im new to python and trying to understand data manipulation

```
df
Alpha               AlphaComboCount
12-99                   8039
22-99                   1792
12-99,138-99            1776
12-45,138-45            1585
21-99                   1225
123-99                  1145
121-99                  1102
21-581                  1000
121-99,22-99             909
32-99                    814
21-141                   75
12-581,12-99             711
347-99                   685
2089-281                 685
123-49,121-29,22-79      626
121-99,123-99,22-99      4
```

As you can see above, there are two columns. Alpha being a string made out of concatenation of 2 codes seperated by '-'. My objective is to find the aggregate percentage of alphacombocount by the first code.
For example:

where there is 21 subcode-

```
Alpha   AlphaComboCount  Percent
21-99   1225             53%
21-141    75             3.2%
21-581  1000            43.3%
```

The objective as you see above is to get a corresponding percentage. since the total aggregrate here is 2300 of the 21 subcode.

Where it gets more complicated is for combination codes:

```
   123-49,121-29,22-79       626  99%
    121-99,123-99,22-99      4   0.6%
```

As you see above, all the first sub codes are the same but rearranged. This is also a valid case to get percentage values. As long as the combination is the same of the first subcode before'-'. How can i go about this to get the percentage values for all alpha combinations? is there an algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to separate the codes within a cell, then you can extract the first code and groupby:

```
# separate the codes
tmp = df.assign(FirstCode=df.Alpha.str.split(','))

# extract the first code
tmp['FirstCode'] = [tuple(sorted(set(x.split('-')[0] for x in cell)))
                        for cell in tmp.FirstCode]

# sum per each first codes with groupby
sum_per_code = tmp['AlphaComboCount'].groupby(tmp['FirstCode']).transform('sum')

# percentage is just a simple division
tmp['Percent'] = tmp['AlphaComboCount']/sum_per_code

# let's print the output:
print(tmp.sort_values('FirstCode'))
```

Output:

```
                  Alpha  AlphaComboCount       FirstCode   Percent
0                 12-99             8039           (12,)  0.918743
11         12-581,12-99              711           (12,)  0.081257
2          12-99,138-99             1776       (12, 138)  0.528414
3          12-45,138-45             1585       (12, 138)  0.471586
6                121-99             1102          (121,)  1.000000
14  123-49,121-29,22-79              626  (121, 123, 22)  0.993651
15  121-99,123-99,22-99                4  (121, 123, 22)  0.006349
8          121-99,22-99              909       (121, 22)  1.000000
5                123-99             1145          (123,)  1.000000
13             2089-281              685         (2089,)  1.000000
4                 21-99             1225           (21,)  0.532609
7                21-581             1000           (21,)  0.434783
10               21-141               75           (21,)  0.032609
1                 22-99             1792           (22,)  1.000000
9                 32-99              814           (32,)  1.000000
12               347-99              685          (347,)  1.000000
```

Comment: @JoeTha where did you get the `3000`?  In my output, it's `1225/(75+1225+1000) = 0.4343`

Comment: Quang, pls accept my apology. that was an error on my end. but the issue still persists regarding the combination codes. As you see in my initial dataframe (df). the last two rows of data. these cannot be completeley seperated because it is the combination that makes a subcode.what i mean is that the percentage value should be applied in the same logic i mentioned in the second half of my question since 123,121,22 form a subcode category based on which the percentage must be determined. total of which in this case is 630

Comment: @JoeTha see my updated answer if it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of codes in *Alpha* column, in different order,
then one of possible solutions is to extract one of them (e.g. minimal),
then take the part before '-', save it in a new column and use in further
processing:

```
df['Alpha_1'] = df.Alpha.str.split(',')\
    .apply(lambda lst: min(lst)).str.split('-', expand=True)[0]
```

The result is:

```
                  Alpha  AlphaComboCount Alpha_1
0                 12-99             8039      12
1                 22-99             1792      22
2          12-99,138-99             1776      12
3          12-45,138-45             1585      12
4                 21-99             1225      21
5                123-99             1145     123
6                121-99             1102     121
7                21-581             1000      21
8          121-99,22-99              909     121
9                 32-99              814      32
10               21-141               75      21
11         12-581,12-99              711      12
12               347-99              685     347
13             2089-281              685    2089
14  123-49,121-29,22-79              626     121
15  121-99,123-99,22-99                4     121
```

To compute percentage of *AlphaComboCount* in each group (with
particular value of *Alpha_1*), define the following function:

```
def proc(grp):
    return (grp.AlphaComboCount / grp.AlphaComboCount.sum()
        * 100).apply('{0:.2f}%'.format)
```

Group *df* by *Alpha_1* and apply this function, saving the result
in *Grp_pct* column:

```
df['Grp_pct'] = df.groupby('Alpha_1').apply(proc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

To inspect the result easily, with rows from each group together,
print *df* the following way:

```
print(df.sort_values('Alpha_1'))
```

getting:

```
                  Alpha  AlphaComboCount Alpha_1  Grp_pct
0                 12-99             8039      12   66.38%
2          12-99,138-99             1776      12   14.66%
3          12-45,138-45             1585      12   13.09%
11         12-581,12-99              711      12    5.87%
6                121-99             1102     121   41.73%
8          121-99,22-99              909     121   34.42%
14  123-49,121-29,22-79              626     121   23.70%
15  121-99,123-99,22-99                4     121    0.15%
5                123-99             1145     123  100.00%
13             2089-281              685    2089  100.00%
4                 21-99             1225      21   53.26%
7                21-581             1000      21   43.48%
10               21-141               75      21    3.26%
1                 22-99             1792      22  100.00%
9                 32-99              814      32  100.00%
12               347-99              685     347  100.00%
```

Now, e.g. compare the section concerning *Alpha_1 == 21* with
your expected result for subcode *21*.